# spring MVC filtering results with html options

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Picture a simple application that displays a list of students.

I am trying to figure out the concept here.  The code in my example is hopefully explains that.

you have a controller `findStudents()`

You have a webpage that displays a list students.  At the top of the webpage is a list of filter options.  Think a form with select options such as country, date enrolled, status, courses etc and a submit button.  The webpage sends a http ajax request to a controller and passes the filterOptions arguments in as an array.  The controller should then return a list of filtered students as a json array.

Here is my thinking so far.  In this example I would like to filter on the date enrolled  (and possibly others but for sake of simplicity ive picked one - not all the filter options may be selected at once).

Is my code example below on the right path?  I sense a code smell.

Some things im not sure of are.

- Would the filterOptions be stored as an entity? e.g. ArrayList of
  countries to filter the results on..  e.g. show me students in UK,
  Ireland, France etc...
- Would I need to use a service?
- How should StudentsJpaRepository look?

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/find-students", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> PostFormDataByMap(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> filterOptions) {

    List<BeatRate> students = studentsJpaRepository.findAllWithFilters(filterOptions);

    return obj;
}
```

**interface**

```
@Repository
public interface StudentsJpaRepository  {
    public List<Student> findAll();
    public List<Student> findAllWithFilters();
}
```

**dao - studentsJpaRepositoryImpl**

```
public List<Student> findWithFilter(HashMap filterOptions<String, String>) {
    String sql =
            "SELECT " +
                    "id",
                    "first-name, " +
                    "address, " +
                    "course," +
                    "age," +
                    "date_enroled"  
                    "FROM " +
                    "BeatRate ";

    if(filterOptions.get("date_enroled")){
        sql = sql+" WHERE date_enroled = "+filterOptions.get("date_enroled");
    }

    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql, Student.class).setMaxResults(10);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Comment: just FYI, your findWithFilter method is likely vulnerable to SQL Injection and could be a serious security issue for your application if you don't fix it. You should not concatenate parameters that are under user control (date_enroled) using String addition. You should use parametrized query (e.g. `+ "WHERE date_enroled = ?"` and then apply the variable parameter using `query.setParameter(...)`

Comment: The @Service interface and its implementation is the place from where you should invoke the repository. Thats the proper design of an Spring App.
Also about Repository, the repository interface should be extended from JPARepository and override the methods if you want to customized functionalities.